# Jira - Estimated Ticket Completion Date Report

Tags: jira

We are looking for a report to generate in JIRA that can be used to get **a list of when we can expect tickets to get completed**.

Consider we have the following information:

- Ticket Rank
- Ticket Developer
- Ticket Estimated Hours
- Ticket Status (In progress / Currently being worked on, In Development Queue, Completed, Hold, Etc)

Ideally this report would **output the date we would expect to see each ticket completed** considering each developer can only work on one ticket at a time, they follow the ticket rank and the meet the estimated hours.

The report would consider 8 hours in a workday, no work on the weekends. To have this adjustable per developer would be preferred, so we could account for part time developers.

BONUS: Displaying each developer's remaining assigned ticket hours.

Any reports out there that get close to this?
Any recommendations on how to build a report that would do this?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: https://support.atlassian.com/

Comment: Are you asking how to implement such a report or are you asking for a plugin or something similar that generates such a report? In the former case, the question would be too broad and in the latter case it would be off-topic, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily resolve this problem with portofolio plugin.

Here is the link where you can download it: https://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/portfolio

Creating report with this plugin will display you all wanted informations from above.

Reports are picturesque and detailed.

Here is the documentation for Portfolio:

https://confluence.atlassian.com/jiraportfoliocloud/portfolio-for-jira-home-715263250.html

And here is the video tuttorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LexaHkZls3g

The main thing is in configuration of plugin,when you set your requirements the reports will be displayed in wanted form.